# Two or more CSS styles are being used when displaying the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using JavaScript to select different CSS styles for different types of accessibly options eg. black on white text, larger text.. The problem I have is when you change the CSS sheet it uses elements from previously selected sheets. You can see what I mean more clearly by looking at the website [here](http://jamesblanksby.webspace.virginmedia.com/) (Doesn't display correctly in IE). If you click the different [Aa] options you can change the style. I am doing this using this code (JavaScript):

```
if ($.cookie("css")) {
    $("link").attr("href", $.cookie("css"));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accessibility a").click(function() {
        $("link").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel'));
        $.cookie("css", $(this).attr('rel'), {
            expires: 365,
            path: '/'
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
```

and the HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="index.css"><img src="images/bonw.png"></a>
<a href="#" rel="index_wonb.css"><img src="images/wonb.png"></a>
<a href="#" rel="index_+.css"><img src="images/+.png"></a>
```

I have no idea why it is doing this and any help would be amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple css sheets on one page, your adding a css page not selecting a new one. try having the page reload with the new css.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would achieve this?

Comment: sorry i just looked at your html, maybe make the default css load through the javascript, because you have index.css in the html file it will always be used and the new css files will only overwrite whatever they change

Answer (score 0):

you could do "body ids"

you attach either a class or an id to the body to tell the page what type of style you want. then in your css, you affix body.[class] or body#[id] for each selector in that sheet corresponding to it's style.

[in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8uDX/), i toggle the text between two styles just by changing the class in the body.

#### HTML

```
<!--initial style red-->
<body class="red">
    <div>click anywhere to toggle styles</div>​
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
/*on one sheet, you can define the page's CSS when the body is red*/
body.red div{
    color:red;
}

/*on another sheet, different when the body is blue*/
body.blue div{
    color:blue;
}​
```

#### JS

```
$(function() {

    var $body = $('body');

    $body.on('click', function() {

        //we toggle the body class, effectively toggling between sheets
        if ($body.hasClass('red')) {
            $body.removeClass('red');
            $body.addClass('blue');
        } else {
            $body.addClass('red');
            $body.removeClass('blue');
        }

    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jQuery toggleClass() http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
It could decrease code count and make it more clear.

```
  $body.toggleClass('red');
  $body.toggleClass('blue');
```